# How can I storage 2 values into one state in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, object

I am new to react native and redux.
The scenario is I want to edit some information in profile page .

Let’s say the code similar as below:

```
export default function Profile () {
const [a,setA] = useState(null)
const [b,setB] = useState(null)

Const handle = (a,b) => {storage.dispatch({type:’change’:{payload:{ email:a , password: b}})

return (
<>
{Item.map(val => 
<TextArea value = {a || val.email}
onChangeText={t => setA(t)}>
)}
{Item2.map(val2=> 
<TextArea value = {b|| val2.password}
onChangeText={t => setB(t)}>
)}
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => handle(a,b)}>Save <TouchableHighlight/>
</>
)
}
```

The question is how can I storage 2 value into one state??
Since without filling the new data, the value is null, not the current data, anyone can help me? Thanks a lot !

Comment: you can store an object `{}` in state same as any value, so you can save `{ a: "1", b: "2" }` as your value.

Comment: can u give me more example? since <TextArea value = {a || val.email}/> , a is upcoming value , val.email is the data fetch from server ,  i want to dynamically save the data into server .  If the user did not fill in the blank , the current value is still can save and pass it to server